# Using Mono and Optional together

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

One of the things I'm trying to wrap my head around with reactive programs is dealing with no results appropriately.

Let's say I had an API that optionally retrieved the latest order for a user. I want to leave the behavior of if there is no user found up to the caller. In plain old java, I would write something like:

`Optional<Order> getLatestOrder(int userId) { ... }`

In webflux, I'm trying to wrap my head around if an equivalent function should be returning `Mono<Optional<Order>>` or `Mono<Order>`.

If I add `getLatestOrder()` to a reactive flow, it might stop if I emit an empty mono. It feels weird also to do something like:

`getLatestOrder().defaultIfEmpty(new Order());`

since that now feels like just a sentinel value that's representing that it doesn't exist.

Is there guidance on a pattern with using `Mono` and `Optional`? Is there a proper way to ditch `Optional` completely when you really want to express something is not present?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I started using webflux for a small project and we faced the same question. We decided to return `Mono<Order>`
Most of the time we then use `switchIfEmpty(Mono<? extends T> alternate)` to throw an error or recover with an alternative

In our usecases `switchIfEmpty()` and `defaultIfEmpty()` give us enough control to handle empty results.

Example from the reference guide: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/index.html#_checking_the_execution_path_with_code_publisherprobe_code